# How to correctly set Image Source in XAML (Silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I have two projects in solution. First project has page with image-buttons, second images for this buttons.

I try to set Image Source like this:

```
<telerik:RadButton x:Name="cbRun" Style="{StaticResource FvsToolbarButtonStyle}"
   IsEnabled="True" Visibility="Visible" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Запустить" Click="cbRun_Click">
    <Image Source="/fvsimages;component/forms_ed/Run.png"/>
 </telerik:RadButton>`
```

or like this: `...<Image Source="../fvsimages/forms_ed/Run.png"/>...`

but it doesn't work. (**upd: images are visible in designer, but invisible in debug**)

All works when page and images were in one project. What i do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The images need to have their `Build Action` set to **Resource** when included in library and you need use a path that starts with "/assemblyname;component/"

Comment: I looked and found that their 'Build Action' already set to 'Resource' (i search first a lot of questions on stackoverflow about this problem), and assembly and is 'fvsimages' (i set it manualy in the beginning). I tryed debug with firebug, but found no pictires loaded( only empty buttons.

Comment: @ForeverSmiling:  We're getting in to sticky territory now.  You should check that the assembly name is fvsimages (check in the project properties).  What happens if you get real simple by creating a fresh UserControl that contains just the image element and set this User control as the RootVisual?

Comment: I checked, assambly name is fvsimages. So I do not understand what i do wrong. Now i'will try to create fresh UserControl. I hope this will help me to understand the problem.